# Partition missing and inconsistent partition table

Tags: partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my wife's laptop. Originally there was Win 7 on it and I simply wiped out everything and used the whole disk for Ubuntu. I followed the following guide to create partitions:
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

After I filled the /home/*user*/... directory with some personal files I received the warning that /root was running out of space.

I checked the space available on the partitions and /home disappeared while /boot dramatically  increased (During the installation, I assigned 500 MB to /boot and 230 GB to /home)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  6,2M  379M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        19G  7,6G   11G  43% /
tmpfs           1,9G   13M  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8       9,1G   22M  8,6G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda7       9,1G  983M  7,7G  12% /var
/dev/sda6       230G  250M  218G   1% /boot
/dev/sda9       185G  9,9G  166G   6% /opt
tmpfs           385M   60K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
```

What happened here? Or maybe.. what did I do wrong here?
Thank you for your time.

**Edit**

`lsblk`:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 465,8G 0 disk 
├─sda9 8:9 0 187,6G 0 part /opt 
├─sda7 8:7 0 9,3G 0 part /var 
├─sda5 8:5 0 19,1G 0 part / 
├─sda1 8:1 0 7,6G 0 part [SWAP] 
├─sda8 8:8 0 9,3G 0 part /tmp 
└─sda6 8:6 0 232,9G 0 part /boot
```

Comment: Could you post output of `lsblk`command?

Comment: Sure!

inline      '  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT'
        sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
       ├─sda9   8:9    0 187,6G  0 part /opt
       ├─sda7   8:7    0   9,3G  0 part /var
       ├─sda5   8:5    0  19,1G  0 part /
       ├─sda1   8:1    0   7,6G  0 part [SWAP]
       ├─sda8   8:8    0   9,3G  0 part /tmp
       └─sda6   8:6    0 232,9G  0 part /boot

Comment: `NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT `

`sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk `
`├─sda9   8:9    0 187,6G  0 part /opt`
`├─sda7   8:7    0   9,3G  0 part /var`
`├─sda5   8:5    0  19,1G  0 part /`
`├─sda1   8:1    0   7,6G  0 part [SWAP]`
`├─sda8   8:8    0   9,3G  0 part /tmp`
`└─sda6   8:6    0 232,9G  0 part /boot`

Comment: I looks like you assigned the 230G partition to /boot instead of /home. If I was you, I would have a 50-80GB / partition with everything in it and an 8G swap. Install Ubuntu and then create partitions in the empty space that are not related to the OS for your data. I would also go with Kubuntu 18.04, which will be stable soon, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Hi Katu,
Thank you for your comment. As I have already mentioned in my original post, during installation I assigned 500 MB to /boot and 230 GB to /home. I do not have proof but I am pretty sure. I followed step by step the guide. Out of the blue the /home partition just disappeared and (I have no clue how) it merged to /boot. No idea what happened there. :(